# Exporting all specflow step definitions to make a tutorial for the tests

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, specflow

I am writing a specflow project, with many features and different steps.
The goal of this project is to give tools for business oriented QA so they'll make good BDD tests.

Now I finished developement and I want to gather all steps together to make a nice wiki tutorial.

Is there a good way to get a list of all the step definitions without copying them manually?

Comment: Do you want to list steps (the given, when, thens in scenarios), or step definitions (the actual code behind each step)?

Comment: I want a list in excel/csv file, that looks something like this:
Step || Step comment || times used
================================

Given I am a new browser || opening a new fire fox browser with clean cookies and cleared cache || 30

When I go to 'url' || Navigate the currently opened firefox instanse to 'url' is possible || 1

Answer (score 4):

[SpecFlow Documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/) for getting a step definitions report:

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport Project.csproj /out:Steps.html
```

Comment: @mosaad It definitely was working in November 2013! Anyway, thanks for update :-)

Comment: It is not working with visual studios 2015, I tried with 2013 it is still working. Probably compatibility issue